# Derivation for mixed distribution, Poisson-Lindley

Tags: distributions, mixed-model, poisson-distribution, marginal-distribution, compound-distributions

I want to derive the Poisson Lindley Distribution.

$$ f_x(x|\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^{x-1}}{(x-1)!}e^{-\lambda}
$$
$$f_x(x|p) = \frac{p^2}{(p+1)}(\lambda+1)e^{-\lambda p}
$$

The Distribution of x, $f_x(x) = \int ^\infty _0 f_x(x|\lambda) f_\lambda(\lambda) \ d\lambda$

Then 
$$ f_x(x) = \frac{p^2}{(p+1)(x-1)!} \int_0^\infty \lambda^{x-1}(\lambda+1) e^{-\lambda (1+p)} \; d\lambda
$$

I broke it as sum of 2 integrals:

$$ f_x(x) = \frac{p^2}{(p+1)(x-1)!}\left[ \int^\infty_0 \lambda^xe^{-\lambda(1+p)} \; d\lambda \ +\int^\infty_0 \lambda^{(x-1)}e^{-\lambda (1+p)} \; d\lambda  \right] 
$$

As I solve $\int ^\infty _0 \lambda^xe^{-\lambda(1+p)} \ d\lambda = \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda(1+p)}}{-(1+p)} +\frac{1}{1+p} \int ^\infty _0 \lambda^{x-1}e^{-\lambda(1+p)} \ d\lambda $

Then rewriting $f_x(x):$
$$f_x(x) = \frac{p^2}{(p+1)(x-1)!} \int^\infty_0 \frac{p+2}{p+1} \lambda^{x-1} e^{-\lambda (1+p)} \; d\lambda
$$

I am unable to proceed further to show that the Poisson-Lindley distribution is:

$$\frac{p^2}{(p+1)^{x+3}}(p+2+x)$$

Comment: You lost me at the outset with your two different, conflicting definitions of "$f_x$."  It appears you meant to write "$f_\lambda(\lambda\mid p)$" in the second instance whereas in the integral you needed to write "$f_\lambda(\lambda\mid p)$" instead of "$f_\lambda(\lambda).$" As far as the mathematics goes, you're just evaluating the sum of Gamma integrals: you can look them up or use the substitution $y=\lambda(1+p).$

Comment: Right, I was supposed to write $f_\lambda (\lambda |p)$, but $\lambda$ is independent of $p$, so can write it as  $f_\lambda (\lambda)$. Thanks for the hint. Shall try it.

Comment: I'm sorry: that makes no sense.

Comment: I tried to fix your $\LaTeX$ markup, please check. But there are still errors/inconsistencies, please fix. As for your question see https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/50968086/j.matcom.2007.11.02120161219-24452-shldvn.pdf?response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DZero-truncated_Poisson_Lindley_distribut.pdf&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A%2F20200112%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200112T205830Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=8a06979414b9579db9cef79d4f17e8f39f64ecd599389cfdcad0e5ad3e97238e

Comment: Other relevant papers https://www.academia.edu/30523770/Lindley_distribution_and_its_application,  https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2529053.pdf?casa_token=jMEoIhS-FFIAAAAA:Keg1FqDMU8GrTzUbx1z8gLmi4sF9Pe3g7dEO0oGU8nkbPI0M8w6h9gNU8S4Sp8RdW9tF3MDK3P8waqXbt616W-QsSt_X24jmS21_nXf8_iCLw2eq9dY